# Wrap a C++ library in Swift code, compile as a Cocoa Touch framework

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a C++ library that is full of warts and weird features, and I want to make it much easier to use (and reuse) in a Swift project. So I intend to wrap this C++ library in some Swift code, then make it available as a Cocoa Touch framework.

I've added both my (fat) `.a` file and the required `.h` files to my project, then added the `.a` to the "Link Binary with Libraries" section of Build Phases, and added the main `.h` file to the Project section of the Headers build phase. But the build fails with:

> Library not found for -lMyLib

I'm obviously missing something here - I'm guessing maybe I need to adjust the Framework Search Path and/or Header Search Path? Or am I missing something more fundamental? My desired end result is a `.framework` another developer can pull into their Swift project without having to do any other build setting tweaks.

Comment: You can't link Swift and C++ directly. You need a C or ObjC wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for "Library Search Paths" (LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS). You may need to add to "Header Search Paths (HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS) as well, depending on your setup. In this case, you shouldn't have to add anything to the Framework search paths, since you are not dealing with a Framework.

(As an aside, you are likely going to find that you have to wrap your C++ library in Objective-C++ code to expose the functionality to Swift.)

Comment: Either Objective-C++ or a C shim. The latter would be more light weight, but possibly harder work.